# Using Resource Routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have what I think is probably a pretty simple question.

I generated a resource route for my class 'Orders', as they will need to be created, destroyed, edited, viewed, etc.

I have a spot in my app where I want to load all orders via AJAX which are currently 'outstanding' (!= finished).

I think I'm supposed to use the orders.show route for this, yes? My only confusion comes in the URI whereby it says to access the orders.show route, you need to specify an order, like so:

order/{order}

[image]

If I want to use AJAX to talk to my controller such that the controller returns a list of orders that it grabs from the database where status != completed, what do I specify in the URI? I don't want to grab ONE order, I want to grab SEVERAL.

From my controller:

```
  public function show(Order $order){
    $orders = Order::where('status', '!=' , 'Received')->get();
    return $orders;
  }
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `show` method is when you're returning a single resource - a single order. That's why it takes a reference to the order as part of the route.

The `index` method is the one that returns a collection of a resource - multiple orders. You can go about this a number of ways: you could have a regular `OrdersController` that returns all orders by default, but a query parameter might restrict is base on status, or you could create a specific `OutstandingOrdersController` which returns just those orders.

Here's an example of how you might go about it the first way.

```
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::query();

        if (request()->has('outstanding')) {
            $orders->where('status', '!=', 'Received');
        }

        return $orders->get();
    }
}
```

Then, your Ajax library can do `GET /orders` for all orders, or `GET /orders?outstanding` to only retrieve outstanding orders. You might also consider taking a `status` parameter to the query to only retrieve orders of a certain status.